# Vector geometry proofs

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors, polar-coordinates

Prove that all the roots of the equation $$z^n \cos(n \alpha)+z^{n-1} \cos((n-1) \alpha)+ \cdots +z \cos(\alpha)=1$$, where alpha is real, lie outside the circle $|z|=1/2$.
How do I approach this question?

Comment: I have used [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to edit your question. If this isn't what you mean, you can change it yourself.

Comment: Also, have you tried using the multiple-angle formula $\cos(nx) = 2 \cos[(n-1)x] - \cos[(n-2)x]$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Using de Moivre's identity and calling $Z = z(\cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha)$ we arrive at

$$
\frac{Z^{n+1}-1}{Z-1}-1=1\Rightarrow \mbox{Re}(2Z-Z^{n+1})=1
$$

or equivalently

$$
2|Z|\cos\alpha = 1+|Z|^{n+1}\cos((n+1)\alpha)
$$

Answer (score 0):

let $z=re^{i\beta}$ then 
$$
\cos(m\alpha)=\frac{e^{im\alpha}+e^{-im\alpha}}{2}
$$
and you calculate the sum 
$$
1=\sum_{m=1}^{n}{z\cos(m\alpha)}
$$
(this sum is sum two geometric progresion sum)
and $Re(1)=1,\>Im(1)=0$.